# Laravel 10: Undefined variable $products

Tags: php, laravel

Im new to lavarel, can you help me on this. I can't seem to load the homepage after adding @foreach but if I remove it it seems to be fine and works normally.
Snippet from home.blade.php

```
@foreach ($products as $product)
    <tr>
    <td>{{ $product->name }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

The HomeController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Product;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Renderable
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $products = Product::all();
        return view('home', compact('products'));
    }
}
```

Model (Product.php)

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = ['name'];
}
```

and for routing

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider and all of them will
| be assigned to the "web" middleware group. Make something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('home');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');
```

Can't seem to get it working, I'm using chrome btw
Thanks!

Tried to remove the @foreach to just display
`<p>{{ $product->name }}</p>`
but it still has the same error on restart, tried
`php artisan cache:clear`
still didn't work

Comment: try `view('home', ['products' => $products]);`

Comment: in routes you are defining `'/'` and `'/home'` are you sure the problem is in `/home` url.

Comment: @francisco: doesn't `compact("products")` already do this? PHP should expand `compact('products')` into `['products' => $products]` automatically: [PHP compact](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php). Or am I missing something?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels yes probably. With laravel you can develop in many ways, check [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/views#introduction), they don't use the `compact()`. Is that a bad thing?

Comment: @francisco: but Laravel is fully created with and based on PHP, and so good or bad, your comment doesn't appear to be anything that would solve the problem or that could likely help the situation. Just saying.

Comment: @francisco, already tried this too, still with same error

Comment: `view('home', ['products' => $products]);` and `view('home', compact('products'));` are equivalent, and it's mostly up to preference. I prefer `['products' => $products]` syntax, since it also allows inline definition like `['products' => Product::inDefaultOrder()->get()]` so you don't need to define `$products` as a single-use variable. The issue here is `return view('home');` where _nothing_ is being passed to the `home.blade.php`, so if they're on `localhost:8000/`, it would be an error, but `localhost:8000/home` would be fine. View is returned by multiple routes with different data.

Comment: @Axol Following the above comment, simply change your code to `Route::get('/', function() { return redirect()->route('home'); });` and your code will work. You're not passing any data to your view via `return view('home');`, so if you make `/` redirect to `/home` where you _are_ returning data, you'll be fine. Or simply remove `Route::get('/', ...);` completely. Up to you.

Answer (score 2):

In your routes file, you have:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('home');
});
```

This route returns the home view directly without going through your HomeController. As a result, the `$products` variable is not being passed to the view, leading to the error you're seeing.

To fix this, update your root route to use the HomeController so that the products are fetched and passed to the view:

```
Route::get('/', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index']);
```